Interpreting the rows and columns of the attention Heatmap
I have a simple question to which I didn't find an answer:
How to read the attention heatmap ? Rows attend to Columns or Columns attend to Rows
Since it isn't symmetric sometimes, like in this plot, we see the diagonal is shifted by one down, do we here say that the tokens are attending most to the precedent token or to the next token ? (without considering the exceptions)
If the answer is precedent token, it means that the rows are attending to the columns
e.g. CTTCTG (2nd token) is attending the most to CTGATGA (1st token).
If the answer is next token, it means that the columns are attending to the rows
e.g. CTGATGA (1st token) is attending the most to CTTCTG (2nd token).
If you have any article where I can read about the interpretations of the attention heatmaps, please refer to it, I'd like to understand more the role of different heads, and how visualizing different layers can be useful, if it is.
Thank you

